# Import piped file in memoq

Tags: regex

I need to import a piped file in excel in memoq so that I get different segments for every text delimited by the pipe and when exporting to be able to reconsolidate the translation piped as the source.

Would it be a regex to make a rule for this?

Comment: fixed a typo for you

Answer (score 0):

This will catch everything until it hits a |

```
[^\|]+
```

Comment: but this would not leave out the last text that appears as that one does not have a space and pipe after anymore

Comment: as it is:  bla | blabla | Bla  and I just need to import the text

Comment: @LoredanaAdina So you only want the one surrounded by pipes? blabla but not bla or Bla?

Comment: I want all text that is separated by pipes. bla blabla and Bla

Comment: basically I have this text separated by pipes and I need to import this into memoq as separated segment without the pipe sign. I hope this makes sense. to appear like:

Comment: bla
blabla
Bla              instead of a full bla | blabla | Bla

Comment: Maybe you should just replace pies with nothing?

Comment: but if I replace pipes with nothing then I can't import this as separate segment or reconsolidate back to pipes when I export the file.

Comment: I would need a rule that matches all before | and after

Comment: @LoredanaAdina my answer does this, it matches everything between, before or after pipes separately, I don't understand the issue you're having